# How to do loop calculations in R?

Tags: r, loops, calculation

My case is that I have a data file for each commodity, I write the data file like this into R:

```
price_data <- read.table("commodityA.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE, dec=",")
```

Then I get the following table as a data frame:

```
TIME                  return 
...                   ...
2005-01-05 10:15:00   0.5  
2005-01-05 10:16:00   0.6  
2005-01-05 10:17:00   0.3 
2005-01-05 10:18:00   0.1
2005-01-05 10:19:00   0.5
2005-01-05 10:20:00   0.5  
2005-01-05 10:21:00   0.2  
2005-01-05 10:22:00   0.5 
2005-01-05 10:23:00   0.2
2005-01-05 10:24:00   0.5
```

Above is the data for one commodity.
Additionally to that I have data frame that looks like this:

```
TIME                 Event Type                 
2004-12-15 12:45:00  A
2005-01-05 10:20:00  B
2005-10-31 11:05:00  C
```

I am trying to find a way to connect the events of Excel with the financial data.
So for example, for the second event at `2005-01-05 10:20:00`.
This event will be `t=0` with a return of `0.5`. The minute before will be `t=-1` while the minute after the event is `t=1`.

I want to compare the three given returns of the three `t` here with the expected return to check for abnormalities... Therefore I need a mean of return for the dates that were before.
Let's take a timeframe with four minutes here, e.g.`t=-5 to t=-2`, so we have:

```
2005-01-05 10:15:00   0.5  
2005-01-05 10:16:00   0.6  
2005-01-05 10:17:00   0.3 
2005-01-05 10:18:00   0.1
```

Mean-Calculation: `(0.5+0.6+0.3+0.1)/4 = 0.375`.
Then check for abnormalities for the three `t`

```
t=-1:  0.5 - 0.375 =  0.125
t= 0:  0.5 - 0.375 =  0.125
t= 1:  0.2 - 0.375 = -0.175
```

Then write the results to a data frame and later into excel with following structure, to get the following list in the end:

```
TIME                 Event Type  t=-1   t= 0  t= 1
2004-12-15 12:45:00  A           ...    ...   ...
2005-01-05 10:20:00  B           0.125  0.125 -0.175
2005-10-31 11:05:00  C           ...    ...   ...
```

Is there a possibility to create a loop or something to do the calculation for all `TIME` given in excel so that I have a complete list of Event time, type and abnormalities? I have more than 50 events in the excel list.

Every help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is trivially simple.

1. Read data from files as you write

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

price_data = tribble(
 ~TIME, ~return,
 "2005-01-05 10:15:00", 0.5,
 "2005-01-05 10:16:00", 0.6,
 "2005-01-05 10:17:00", 0.3,
 "2005-01-05 10:18:00", 0.1,
 "2005-01-05 10:19:00", 0.5,
 "2005-01-05 10:20:00", 0.5,
 "2005-01-05 10:21:00", 0.2,
 "2005-01-05 10:22:00", 0.5,
 "2005-01-05 10:23:00", 0.2,
 "2005-01-05 10:24:00", 0.5
) %>% mutate(TIME = ymd_hms(TIME))

event_data = tribble(
  ~TIME,                 ~Event.Type,
  "2004-12-15 12:45:00", "A",
  "2005-01-05 10:20:00", "B",
  "2005-01-05 10:21:00", "C",
  "2005-01-05 10:23:00", "A",
  "2005-10-31 11:05:00", "C"
) %>% mutate(TIME = ymd_hms(TIME))
```

2. Prepare a function that will do the calculations as you wrote it

```
f1 = function(event_time, price_data){
  out = tibble(`t-1` = NA, t0 = NA, `t+1`=NA)
  idx = which(price_data$TIME==event_time)
  if(length(idx)==0) return(out)
  if(idx<6) return(out)
  if(idx>(nrow(price_data)-1)) return(out) 
  mt2t5 = mean(price_data$return[(idx-5):(idx-2)])
  tibble(`t-1` = price_data$return[idx-1] - mt2t5, 
         t0 = price_data$return[idx] - mt2t5, 
         `t+1` = price_data$return[idx+1] - mt2t5) 
}
```

3. Make a mutation

```
event_data %>% 
  mutate(data = map(TIME, f1, price_data)) %>% 
  unnest(data)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  TIME                Event.Type  `t-1`     t0  `t+1`
  <dttm>              <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2004-12-15 12:45:00 A          NA     NA     NA    
2 2005-01-05 10:20:00 B           0.125  0.125 -0.175
3 2005-01-05 10:21:00 C           0.125 -0.175  0.125
4 2005-01-05 10:23:00 A           0.175 -0.125  0.175    
5 2005-10-31 11:05:00 C          NA     NA     NA
```

And it's ready!

However, do not miss the appropriate security features in the `f1` function. These are the indices `idx<6` and `idx>(nrow(price_data)-1)`

**Update**

Ok, let's try to modify our function `f1` so that `t1` and `t2` are arguments that take whatever value you want.
Here is the corrected code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

price_data = tribble(
 ~TIME, ~return,
 "2005-01-05 10:10:00", 0.5,
 "2005-01-05 10:11:00", 0.6,
 "2005-01-05 10:12:00", 0.3,
 "2005-01-05 10:13:00", 0.1,
 "2005-01-05 10:14:00", 0.5,
 "2005-01-05 10:15:00", 0.5,
 "2005-01-05 10:16:00", 0.6,
 "2005-01-05 10:17:00", 0.3,
 "2005-01-05 10:18:00", 0.1,
 "2005-01-05 10:19:00", 0.5,
 "2005-01-05 10:20:00", 0.5,
 "2005-01-05 10:21:00", 0.2,
 "2005-01-05 10:22:00", 0.5,
 "2005-01-05 10:23:00", 0.2,
 "2005-01-05 10:24:00", 0.5
) %>% mutate(TIME = ymd_hms(TIME))

event_data = tribble(
  ~TIME,                 ~Event.Type,
  "2004-12-15 12:45:00", "A",
  "2005-01-05 10:20:00", "B",
  "2005-01-05 10:21:00", "C",
  "2005-01-05 10:23:00", "A",
  "2005-10-31 11:05:00", "C"
) %>% mutate(TIME = ymd_hms(TIME))


f1 = function(event_time, price_data, t1=2, t2=-2){
  out = tibble(`t-1` = NA, t0 = NA, `t+1`=NA)
  idx = which(price_data$TIME==event_time)
  if(length(idx)==0) return(out)
  if((idx+t1)<1 | (idx+t2)<1 | 
     (idx+t1)>nrow(price_data) | (idx+t2)>nrow(price_data) | 
     idx==(nrow(price_data)-1) | idx==1) return(out)
  mt1t2 = mean(price_data$return[(idx+t1):(idx+t2)])
  tibble(`t-1` = price_data$return[idx-1] - mt1t2,
         t0 = price_data$return[idx] - mt1t2,
         `t+1` = price_data$return[idx+1] - mt1t2)
}

event_data %>%
  mutate(data = map(TIME, f1, price_data, 2, -8)) %>%
  unnest(data)
```

ouyput

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  TIME                Event.Type  `t-1`     t0  `t+1`
  <dttm>              <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2004-12-15 12:45:00 A          NA     NA     NA    
2 2005-01-05 10:20:00 B           0.127  0.127 -0.173
3 2005-01-05 10:21:00 C           0.136 -0.164  0.136
4 2005-01-05 10:23:00 A          NA     NA     NA    
5 2005-10-31 11:05:00 C          NA     NA     NA
```

Finally, a few remarks and comments.
When doing index manipulations, you must always be careful not to go beyond the permissible ranges of vector or data frame indices. In this case, we must make sure that the indices are always in the range `1: nrow (price_data)`.
So we have to control the parameters `t1` and `t2` and if they cause going beyond the permissible indices, react accordingly. In this case the `NA` response seems to be appropriate (`if((idx+t1)<1 | ...idx==1) return(out)`).

Of course, the index cannot be a empty value, and this is what happens when the `TIME` value from the `event_data` tibble is not found in the `price_data` tibble (`if(length(idx)==0) return(out)`).

**Update 2**

```
f2 = function(event_time, price_data, t1=2, t2=-2){
  out = tibble(`t-2` = NA, `t-1` = NA, t0 = NA, `t+1`=NA, `t+2`=NA)
  idx = which(price_data$TIME==event_time)
  if(length(idx)==0) return(out)
  if((idx+t1)<1 | (idx+t2)<1 |
     (idx+t1)>nrow(price_data) | (idx+t2)>nrow(price_data) |
     idx==(nrow(price_data)-1) | idx==1 |
     idx==(nrow(price_data)-2) | idx==2) return(out)
  mt1t2 = mean(price_data$return[(idx+t1):(idx+t2)])
  tibble(`t-2` = price_data$return[idx-2] - mt1t2,
         `t-1` = price_data$return[idx-1] - mt1t2,
         t0 = price_data$return[idx] - mt1t2,
         `t+1` = price_data$return[idx+1] - mt1t2,
         `t+2` = price_data$return[idx+2] - mt1t2)
}

event_data %>%
  mutate(data = map(TIME, f2, price_data, 2, -8)) %>%
  unnest(data)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 7
  TIME                Event.Type  `t-2`  `t-1`     t0  `t+1`  `t+2`
  <dttm>              <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2004-12-15 12:45:00 A          NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
2 2005-01-05 10:20:00 B          -0.273  0.127  0.127 -0.173  0.127
3 2005-01-05 10:21:00 C           0.136  0.136 -0.164  0.136 -0.164
4 2005-01-05 10:23:00 A          NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
5 2005-10-31 11:05:00 C          NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

Comment: In lines 3 and 4 of the `event_data` table, I wrote events C and B just for this, so that I have more data to test the function. Nothing else.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the solution that finally solves your problem.

Comment: The value `tibble (" t-1 "= NA," t0 "= NA," t + 1 "= NA)` is returned by the `f1` function when this function cannot return valid results because the indexes exceed  `1: nrow (price_data)`. The fact that `price_data` contains all the values that are in event_data was not so obvious. For example, it was in the example data you provided. For this I control the `length (idx) == 0`

Comment: It has to be like this, because, for example, what happens if the `event_data` is on the first index in `price_data`? How to calculate `t-1`? What if `event_data` is on the last index in `price_data`? How do I get `t+1`? Not to mention, you can try to cross the indices yourself by specifying too much (or too little) for `t1` and `t2`. Write your program in such a way that you always anticipate possible problems.

Comment: I added update 2 with function `f2` returning `t-2, t-1, t0, t1, t2`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the data in two data frames price_data and event_data with both a column named TIME used to merge, this should do the trick

```
all_data <- merge(price_data, event_data, all=TRUE)
all_data <- cbind(all_data,"t-1"=c(NA,all_data[,2][-nrow(all_data)]),"t"=all_data[,2],"t+1"=c(all_data[,2][-1],NA))
all_data[,2] <- round(rowMeans(all_data[,4:6]),2)
all_data[,4:6] <- all_data[,4:6]-all_data[,2]
```